# Angularjs permits update of a single(first) row for sub comments of each post

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs having issues in updating each subcommets/subpost of inputted data.

I have a json file which contains **two posts**. The **First Post** contains ** three** subposts(subcomment) each with an update button.  The **second post** contains **two** subpost(subcomment) each with an update button.

My intention was to allow user to input any values corresponding to each rows under each post so the new inputed data will replace the already existing data in the angular js view for that row.

The problem is that only the first row of each subcomment for that post gets updated when data is posted.

For instance in **post 1**, If you enter a value at the **first row** and submit, it will update the already existing `{{comment.subcomment}}` data of the first row.  If you input on row 2 for the same **post 1**, it will update the first row of post 1 instead of second row of that post.

Some Stackoverflow scholars like **NTP** in the link below
[Angularjs allows data updates only for the first rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785966/angularjs-allows-data-updates-only-for-the-first-rows/50791338#50791338)

suggested solution that since the code has 2 `ng-repeats` and `$index` passes the index of the inner ng-repeat whereas one need the index of the outer `ng-repeat`. He concluded that if one modify code to take the index of outer **ng-repeat** as following, it should solve the issue.

1) First add this ng-init to your outer ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat='post in posts track by $index' ng-init="outerIndex=$index">
```

2) use outerIndex in your save function

```
<input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save and Replace/Update' ng-click='setResponse4(post.id,1,outerIndex,subcomment,comment.id)'>
```

But the solution above only updates first inputed values of the of the first subcomment row for each post. 
If you input on row 2 for the same, it will update the first row of that post instead of second row of that post for which the button was clicked.

below is the code

js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.posts = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "my first post title.",
            "comment": [
                {
                    "subcomment": "post 1 subcomment 1", "status": "**working**"
                },

                {
                    "subcomment": "post 1 subcomment 2", "status": "**Not working**"
                },

                {
                    "subcomment": "post 1 sub comment 3", "status": "**Not working**"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "my second post title.",
            "comment": [
                {
                    "subcomment": "post 2 subcomment 1", "status": "**working**"
                },

                {
                    "subcomment": "post 2 subcomment 2", "status": "**Not working**"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    $scope.setResponse4 = function (postid, type, index, subcomment, commentid) {
        var subcomment = subcomment;
        $scope.posts[index].comment[0].subcomment = subcomment;
    }
});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
        <div ng-repeat='post in posts track by $index' ng-init="outerIndex=$index">
            <h3>
                <b>Post ID: {{ post.id }}</b>
            </h3>
            <b>Post Title:</b> {{ post.title }}
            <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comment ">
                <br>
                <b>sub comment</b>: {{comment.subcomment}},
                <b>status</b>: {{comment.status}},
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Enter subcomment</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='text' ng-model='subcomment' placeholder="Enter Value For subcomment and Save.">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{outerIndex}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save and Replace/Update' ng-click='setResponse4(post.id,1,outerIndex,subcomment,comment.id)'>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type='button' style="display:none" ng-init='getComments1(comment.id,5)'>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="width:100%;font-size:10">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the elements of your comments array you need the index of your inner ng-repeat, Try the following.

1) modify your setResponse4 function to take index of inner ng-repeat and use this index instead of 0.

```
$scope.setResponse4 = function (postid, type, index,innerIndex, subcomment, commentid) {
    var subcomment = subcomment;
    $scope.posts[index].comment[innerIndex].subcomment = subcomment;
}
```

2) initialise innerIndex

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in post.comment" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
```

3) pass innerIndex to your function

```
<input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save and Replace/Update' ng-click='setResponse4(post.id,1,outerIndex,innerIndex,subcomment,comment.id)'>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/GM1oLPBJmXFRLK2DAn4F?p=preview)**

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thank You Sir. I have the problem that I posted in the past  but no perfect solution yet. Please can you look into it and see if you can help. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707939/infinite-scrolling-partially-working-with-angularjs-php